# Wordpress Styling lost After DB restart

Tags: wordpress, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

Am setting up a WordPress site on an AWS EC2 Instance with the SQL DB on the AWS RDS. The WP comes up well initially but when I restart my database instance, the styling / CSS on the WP is lost.

Is there some configuration that requires modification every time after the DB restart?

Comment: I suspect the IP changes everytime the db is restarted and assume somewhere the older IP is being referred to. Will dig further !!

Answer (score 0):

The public IP of EC2 instance is persisted to the wp_options table.
So every time, the EC2 instance is restarted, a new public IP is assigned.
Updating this table in the DB with new IP address solves the issue.

```
Update <dbname>.wp_options
set option_value='http://<IP>'
where option_id in (1,2);
```